# How to validate asp.net Identity from Winform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, winforms, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I am new to ASP.NET and have created an MVC 5 ASP.Net 4.5.2 solution with a web site or web app, a MSSQL DB and a WinForm.  I used the Contoso University template as an example found > [here.](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) <

The winform can connect the DB and the Web App can create user identities.

How do I validate a user identity from the WinForm?  I can access dbo.ASPNetUsers table in MSSQL.  Perhaps I use Client Application Services or WCF or what?  Any input even on what to google would be appreciated.  The Client Application Services Walk Through found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546195.aspx) doesn't seem to apply to VS2015/.Net 4.5+ but is the best resource I have found so far.

Comment: You can take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20957898/3110834) but I think it's better to expose some authentication and authorization service and use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new method in WCF to validate your users if it does not exist already and can call it in the same way as you are calling it in web application. If user is valid then you can set user's identity in a static variable in window application. static variable will sustain that value throughout the application. When user logs out the make that variable to null.